# Mysql multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, row

I want to insert project tasks into a table when a new project is created. I want to achieve this with triggers, but do not know if I can use them multiple times.

Here is the example

```
insert into project_tasks(id,name,name2)
select concat('1',left(project.name,5),left(project.id,30)) as id,
'first task','do this'       
from projects where project_type = '1'
`$`limit 1
```

Here is my problem.

If  `project type = 2`, I want to insert a set of values, if `project type = 3` I want to insert another set of values etc.

For some project types I have six tasks, so if I did not have to do a select to do a relationship i could just have done (1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
,(7,8,9) but now i have to do a insert into for every task, so it will load all tasks

Comment: Read the 7th time, still makes no sense to me.

Comment: ok easier. i have projects and project tasks. if project type = write code then 5 project tasks needs to be created. task 1 - " get info" - task 2 - "start code" - etc.  when project typr = create website  tasks needs to be created task 1 - "get server details" task 2 - "make sure all aplication are loaded" - etc. and so on and so on.

Comment: This si on sugarcrm 4.5. if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could write a stored procedure for each of the cases you try to address and make the trigger decide which stored procedure is appropriate for the case you have.

This is unnecessarily complicated, though, and proves to be a maintenance nightmare once you got too high a number of possible case/value combinations. Personally, I would solve this kind of thing in the Application Layer.

Comment: so how would you do this in php then?

Comment: I would have a set of project type templates (which can come from a database or a textfile or an array) and when a project is created, do a lookup loop, entering the new tasks into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra table for define sets of task for each project. For example

```
project_type - type of project
name1 - predefined string
name2 - predifined string
```

And after create project you can load this data for insert to tasks table. This allow you change sets of task without change base code in your application.

I hope you will understand my main idea